# how to trace a recursive function C++

Tags: c++, function, recursion

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int g(float A[] , int L , int H)
{
   if (L==H)
      if (A[L] > 0.0)
         return 1;
      else 
         return 0;
   int M = (L+H)/2;

   return g(A,L,M)+ g(A,M+1,H);
}
int main (void)
{       
   float A[] = {-1.5 ,3.1,-5.2,0.0};
   g(A,0,3);

   system ("pause");
   return 0;
}
```

its asking me what is return by the function g and what the function does

here is what i got so far

first call is g(A , 0 ,3)
-total skip the IF statement and M = 1 since it its a int 
-return g(A,1,3) + g(A,2 3)

second call 
 - g(A,1,3) skipp the if statement again 
 - M = 0;
 - g(A,2 3) skip the if statement again
 - M= 2;

third call 
-g(A, 0,0,)
  return 0 
-g(A,3,3)
  return 0;

so it just return 0?

and i am guessing it is dividing the middle value and some sort of binary search?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a convoluted way to count how many numbers in the array is greater than 0. And if you try to run this in a compiler, the return value is 1 because the only number that is greater than 0 in the array is 3.1.

at first run:

```
{-1.5, 3.1, -5.2, 0.0}
   0    1     2    3
   L               H
```

then since `L=0` and `H=3`, `M = (0+3)/2 = 3/2 = 1` when you get to `g(A, L, M) + g(A, M+1, H)`, you branch into two:

```
{-1.5, 3.1, -5.2, 0.0}
   0    1     2    3
   L               H
   L1   H1    L2   H2
```

let's do the left part `g(A, L1, H1) = g(A, 0, 1)` first:

```
{-1.5, 3.1, -5.2, 0.0}
   0    1     2    3
   L               H
   L1   H1    L2   H2
   ^^^^^^^
```

again since `L1=0`, `H1=1`, and so `M1 = (0+1)/2 = 1/2 = 0` and you branch into two again `g(A, 0, 0)` and `g(A, 1, 1)`:

```
{-1.5,    3.1,    -5.2, 0.0}
   0       1        2    3
   L               H
   L1      H1      L2    H2
L11,H11 L12,H12
```

on the left part, since `-1.5 <= 0` therefore `g(A, L11, H11) = g(A, 0, 0) = 0`, on the right part, since `3.1 > 0` therefore `g(A, L12, H12) = g(A, 1, 1) = 1`.

So therefore `g(A, 0, 1) = g(A, 0, 0) + g(A, 1, 1) = 1`.

Do the same with `g(A, L2, H2)`, and you get that `g(A, L, H) = g(A, L1, H1) + g(A, L2, H2) = 1 + 0 = 1`.

@Nawaz had a good idea of visualizing this into a binary tree, basically you start with at the root of the tree:

```
{-1.5, 3.1, -5.2, 0.0}
```

At the second layer of iteration, you split the array into two:

```
     {-1.5, 3.1, -5.2, 0.0}
              /   \
             /     \
            /       \
           /         \
   {-1.5, 3.1}    {-5.2, 0.0}
```

At the third layer, you split again:

```
     {-1.5, 3.1, -5.2, 0.0}
              /   \
             /     \
            /       \
           /         \
   {-1.5, 3.1}    {-5.2, 0.0}
      /   \          /   \
     /     \        /     \
 {-1.5}   {3.1}  {-5.2}   {0.0}
```

At this point `L==H` so, we can evaluate the nodes:

```
     {-1.5, 3.1, -5.2, 0.0}
              /   \
             /     \
            /       \
           /         \
   {-1.5, 3.1}    {-5.2, 0.0}
      /   \          /   \
     /     \        /     \
 {-1.5}   {3.1}  {-5.2}   {0.0}
    |       |       |       |
    0       1       0       0
```

and to find the return values, we sum up:

```
     {-1.5, 3.1, -5.2, 0.0}
              /   \
             /     \
            /       \
           /         \
   {-1.5, 3.1}    {-5.2, 0.0}
      0+1=1          0+0=0
```

and lastly

```
     {-1.5, 3.1, -5.2, 0.0}
             1+0=1
```

Answer (score 3):

> and M = 1 since it its a int -return g(A,0,3) + g(A,2 3)

Here is first problem. If M = 1, then how do you say it's `return g(A,0,3) + g(A,2, 3)`?

It should be:

```
return g(A,0,1) + g(A,2, 3)
           //^ this should be 1
```

And since you're wrong at the first step, all the consecutive steps will be wrong.

My suggestion would be :

- Take a pencil and white paper. Be ready to draw a binary tree, that expands downwards
- Write the root node as `g(A,0,3);` . This is the first call.
- Then make two child nodes: left and right
- Write `g(A,0,1)` as the left node, and `g(A,2,3)` as right node.
- Then again make two child nodes of each child, and keep drawing nodes by repeating this step, till the `if` condition becomes true.
- Once the `if` condition becomes true, stop making new nodes (in that branch), and go up towards the root node, summing the values of nodes which you meet on the way.
- What you get at the root node, is the return value of original call from `main()`.

Comment: it should be right i just type it wrong oops. So it is a binary tree? so if it is return 1 it should return the value of the root node. what if it returns 0? Thank you for your reply.

Comment: @ricedragon: Its easy to visualize that as binary tree that grows downward.