# When does the for loop increment occur in this recursive function?

Tags: c++, for-loop

[Manually trace recursive functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21229936/manually-trace-recursive-functions)

In the above question, with the approved answer, it seems that

```cpp
void string_permutation(string str, int mid, int end)
{
    if (mid == end) 
        cout << str << endl;
    else 
    {
        for (int i = mid; i <= end; i++) 
        {
            swap(str[mid], str[i]);
            string_permutation(str, mid + 1, end);
            swap(str[mid], str[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Say we try running the following: `("abcd", 0, 3)`

According to the answer given before, `"bacd"` is the first thing that the string changes to, during the first recursive call (second function call), so the first call + the first recursive call looks like this:

```cpp
("abcd", 0, 3)
("bacd", 1, 3)
```

However, when I was taught the for loop, it was said that the contents of the for loop are done before incrementing (modifying the index).

What that would mean is that before the first recursive call, we have `int i = mid`, this means `mid == 0` and `i == 0` so the swap actually occurring right before the first recursive call is this:
`swap(str[0], str[0]);`, which means the str passed to the recursive call is still `("abcd", 1, 3)`, still `abcd`

So why did the top answer in the other question change the string to `"bacd"`? Is there something I'm missing about for loops? Which one, `i` or `mid` is 1, or is there an error in their answer?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please try to make your questions *self-contained*. That also means you have to show us the code inside the question itself. If you haven't done it yet, then please take some time to read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: `i` does not increment until the recursive function call returns. You just assign it a different value in each recursive call. "*Which one, `i` or `mid` is 1?*" - both. You assign `i` to be equal to the value of `mid`, and `mid` is equal to 1 in the second recursion level.

Comment: I recommend that you learn how to use a debugger. Then you can step through the code statement by statement, and stepping into the recursive calls, to see what's really happening.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Enter the first function call (`mid = 0`, `end = 3`).

   1. Enter first loop iteration (`i = 0 = mid`)
   2. Swap `str[0]` with itself.
   3. Enter second function call (`mid = 1`, `end = 3`).

      1. Enter first loop iteration: `i = mid = 1`.
      2. Swap `str[1]` with itself.
      3. Enter third function call (`mid = 2`, `end = 3`).

         1. Enter first loop iteration: `i = mid = 2`.
         2. Swap `str[2]` with itself.
         3. Enter fourth function call (`mid = end = 3`).

            4. The string has been unchanged so far, so **we print `abcd`.**
         4. Swap `str[2]` with itself.
         5. Enter second loop iteration: `i = 3`
         6. Swap `str[2]` with `str[3]` (`abcd` -> `abdc`).
         7. Enter another function call (`mid = end = 3`).

            4. **We print `abdc`.**
         8. Swap back `str[2]` with `str[3]` (back to `abcd`).
         9. The loop is done.
      4. Swap `str[1]` with itself
      5. Enter second loop iteration: `i = 2`
      6. And so on...

---

Program reproduced here for reading convenience:

```
void string_permutation(string str, int mid, int end)
{
    if (mid == end) 
        cout << str << endl;
    else 
    {
        for (int i = mid; i <= end; i++) 
        {
            swap(str[mid], str[i]);
            string_permutation(str, mid + 1, end);
            swap(str[mid], str[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

---

I believe the answerer of that other question had a different mental model of how to traverse the permutations. In any case, this is what you should see running through a debugger.

---

It's easy to see that this program calls `string_permutation` N! (factorial) times (each call results in `end-mid` more calls where `mid` increases by one). It is also easy to see that each pair of `swap`s restores the string to how it was on function entry. At any given `mid`, the algorithm puts each of the characters from `mid` to `end` at position `mid` and recurses. By induction (base case `mid = end`) we can see that all permutations are accounted for this way.

However, the algorithm doesn't handle duplicate characters correctly. I recommend [`std::next_permutation`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation).